# error installing cmder, which visual c++ redistributable do you suggest?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-c++, cmder

I have visual studio <s>2014</s> 2013

cmder.exe says

[image]

this page https://github.com/bliker/cmder/issues/501   seems to suggest installing the visual c++ redistributable.. some say 2010, some say 2015.

I don't know if I have it. I have Visual Studio 2013. I don't want to end up possibly downgrading what I might have, by installing the C++ redistributable 2010. And I don't want to perhaps get some incompatibility by installing a version like 2015  when I have VS 2013. I'm not even sure if version of C++ (e.g. 2010 , 2015)  redistributable has any relationship with version of visual studio (2013 or 2015).

Comment: You can have every version of the C++ Redistributable installed on the same machine.  What version you need entirely depends on what version the the program uses.  So I suggest you install that version [x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/1/041224F6-A7DC-486B-BD66-%3EBCAAF74B6919/vc_redist.x64.exe) and [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/1/041224F6-A7DC-486B-BD66-BCAAF74B6919/vc_redist.x86.exe).  In simple terms, you don't have the version of the C++ Redistributable, the program requires installed.

Comment: [Evidence](https://github.com/bliker/cmder) - **Update to VS2015.**

Comment: I can find zero evidence of `Visual Studio 2014` even existing.  Are you 100% you have VS2014 installed? [This](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) lists only VS2015, VS2013, and VS2012.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) so what version do you actually have installed?  VS'14 was the codename for Visual Studio 2015.  I still want to know what you have installed exactly.

Comment: AT Ramhound you're right, it was VS 2013 I have (I confused it with SQL 2014!).

Comment: @Ramhound you can post your answer that you can install multiple, i'll accept it.  I see them listed in programs and features, they're quite small I have some e.g. 2005, 2008,... , so I installed more eg  2015 and another year as well, and cmder works now.

Answer (score 0):

ramhound basically answered it, but in the absence of him posting an answer, i'll post it.

> error installing cmder, which visual c++ redistributable do you
>   suggest?

It's normal to have multiple installed. And they're not huge.. recent years are about 20MB.  More give more compatibility.

ctrl panel..programs and features,  shows what ones you have installed. cmder is working now so I installed the right one(s) for it.

[image]